# Upgrade keyboard to another phone's

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note-3, samsung-galaxy-note-8, samsung-galaxy-note-5

I've had three phones in the Samsung Galaxy Note line, a Note 3, a Note 5, and now for a few years I've been using a Note 8. I have enjoyed a keyboard on which I can draw a shape which has a vertex at each letter of the word I want to write, but I'm also perceiving that they're trying to make it smarter, to give it better capabilities faster than they can develop the algorithms that carry out the tasks.

(Some problems I can identify with the Note 8 keyboard is that it is autonomously adopting typos as new words in its dictionary, coming up with new words to suggest or interpret what I draw as, and also sometimes, when I write "something" putting down "s something", repeating the first letter.)

I would really enjoy it if I could upgrade from the native keyboard of my Note 8 to the keyboard which came with one of my earlier phones. Either would be good, though I think the first, that from the Note 3, would be best.

Answer (score 0):

1. I always use (and recommend) SwiftKey, but ...
2. On the phone whose keyboard you like, install APKExtractor (it's in Play and it's free).
3. Extract the keyboard.  (It extracts as an .apk file.)
4. Copy the .apk file to the Note 8.
5. Install it.  You should now have 2 keyboards.  Go into Settings and choose to use the one you just installed.